# I set a top navigation width 0 to hide menus, but why do each menu links still remain?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigation

I have a top navigation bar in my website; On big screens such as laptops, each menu floats horizontally. On small screens such as tablets or smartphones, each menu hides and slides open from the left of the screen only when you click a button above, which looks like three horizontal rows.
I made this happen by setting the width of the top navigation bar 0, so it's not seen.

But, I have no idea why the links still remain and when you try to click the button, you can grab not only the button, but also all of menus. I'd be very appreciated if anyone help me out a bit. Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>untitled</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" onclick="openNav()" class="openbtn">
                <svg>
                    <path d="M0,5 15,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                    <path d="M0,10 15,10" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                    <path d="M0,15 15,15" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_pc" src="img/logo.png"><img class="logo_mobile" src="img/logo_white.png"></a>
            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="closebtn">&times;</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" onclick="closeNav()">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html" onclick="closeNav()">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="art.html" onclick="closeNav()">art</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" onclick="closeNav()">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.width = "100%";}

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.width = "0";}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Navigation Container */
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;                         
    width: 95%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Top Logo */
.logo_pc{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 33px;
}

.logo_mobile{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:42%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 26px;
}

/* Top Navigation Bar */
.topnav{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav li{
    float:left;
}

.topnav li a{
    display: block;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#003366;
}

.topnav li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#cccccc;
}

.openbtn{
    display: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.topnav .closebtn{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width:868px){ 

    /* Top Logo */
    .logo_pc{
        display: none;
    }
    .logo_mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    /* Top Navigation */    
   #wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #003366;
    } 
    .topnav{
        float: none;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin:0;
        padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        transition: 0.5s width ease-in-out;
    }
    .topnav li{
        float: none;
    }
    .topnav li a{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }  
    .openbtn,
    .topnav .closebtn{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a closed tag on `<div id="wrapper">`. Could it be only your problem here!
I tested & seem to work normally. Not sure what you expected
https://jsfiddle.net/j1zgo010/1/

Comment: @ToanLu Thank you for your comment! But, if you look at the result of the jsfiddle, the 'a:link' area is not just the button, but much bigger than that. The reason is that a:link of the four menus still remain even though they are hidden. What I want to do is to limit the 'a:link' area to the button. Any idea to fix this problem?